# Inputting multiple command line arguments with docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I've noticed that `docker-compose run` has command-line input argument functionality with the `-e` flag, where running

```
docker-compose run -e ARG1="val1" -e ARG2="val2"
```

is valid. I'm however using `docker-compose up`, where the flag is not included. I've found a way to include a single variable:

```
ARG1="val1" docker-compose up
```

but how do I add multiple? I've tried separating by comma, semicolon, and others, but there seems to be no way to pass more than one command line argument to docker-compose. I also understand that I can add multiple such values into an `.env` file, but input in the command line is much more convenient for my use case. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax:

```
VAR=value command ...
```

Isn't specific to `docker-compose`; that's just normal shell syntax (for setting temporary environment variables that are only visible to the specified command).

You can add as many variables as you want:

```
ARG1="val1" ARG2="val2" ARG3="val3" docker-compose up
```

These only make sense if your `docker-compose.yaml` references the specific variables.

---

A better option be to use environment files. You can use the `--env-file` option to `docker-compose` to select different environment files, so you can do something like:

```
docker-compose --env-file config1.env up
```

Or

```
docker-compose --env-file config2.env up
```